# Gitlab Template Plain HTML Not Working After Deployed Pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-pages

I’m new to Gitlab, I have created a project name “gitlab-pages-plain-html” from Gitlab template: pages/plain HTML, and the gitlab pipeline to deploy the plain web site to the gitlab pages.

Template example that I get from: Plain HTML site using GitLab Pages

When I went to the Settings/Pages menu, it says Your pages are served under: http://example-group.swaggerui-poc.abc.com/gitlab-pages-plain-html,
and when clicked the link, error of “this site can’t be reached” will be displayed.

I have also check the public folder is there, inside public folder also has index.html

Kindly advise, thanks.